# Artifacts on stars when exporting to FBX

Tags: modeling, export, .fbx, artifacts

I've just finished a Model. When exporting to FBX (and OBJ too), the stars form some weird artifact, which you can see in the images below:

[image: Edit View]

[image: Object View]

[image: Exported View]

The first 2 Pictures show Edit and Object view respectively, and they also show what I want it to look like. The third shows the final result. I don't really know where to start to identify the issue. Any help would be appreciated.